# Python - "xor"ing each byte in "bytes" in the most efficient way

Tags: python, performance

I have a "bytes" object and an "int" mask, I want to do a xor over all the bytes with my mask.
I do this action repeatedly over big "bytes" objects (~ 4096 KB).

This is the code I have which does the work well, only it is very CPU intensive and slows down my script:

```
# 'data' is bytes and 'mask' is int
bmask = struct.pack('!I', mask) # converting the "int" mask to "bytes" of 4 bytes 
a = bytes(b ^ m for b, m in zip(data, itertools.cycle(bmask)))
```

The best I could come up with is this, which is about 20 times faster:

```
# 'data' is bytes and 'mask' is int
# reversing the bytes of the mask
bmask = struct.pack("<I", mask)
mask = struct.unpack(">I", bmask)[0]

# converting from bytes to array of "int"s
arr = array.array("I", data)

# looping over the "int"s
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] ^= mask

# must return bytes
a = bytes(arr)
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a more efficient way to do this (CPU-wize)?
2. Is there a "cleaner" way to do this (without hurting performance)?

P.S. if it is of any importance, I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: What is `data`? Is it a list or bytes or iterator or ..?

Comment: If it is a bottleneck, it could make sense to write a C function called from Python

Comment: "data" is bytes, I'll update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get much faster than your algorithm, using pure Python. (But Fabio Veronese's answer shows that's not true). You can shave off a tiny bit of time by doing the looping in a list comprehension, but then that list needs to be converted back into an array, and the array has to be converted to bytes, so it uses more RAM for a negligible benefit.

However, you can make this *much* faster by using Numpy. Here's a short demo.

```
from time import perf_counter
from random import randrange, seed
import array
import numpy as np

seed(42)

def timed(func):
    ''' Timing decorator '''
    def wrapped(*args):
        start = perf_counter()
        result = func(*args)
        stop = perf_counter()
        print('{}: {:.6f} seconds'.format(func.__name__, stop - start))
        return result
    wrapped.__name__ = func.__name__
    wrapped.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    return wrapped

@timed
def do_mask_arr1(data, mask):
    arr = array.array("I", data)
    # looping over the "int"s
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] ^= mask
    return arr.tobytes()

@timed
def do_mask_arr2(data, mask):
    arr = array.array("I", data)
    return array.array("I", [u ^ mask for u in arr]).tobytes()

@timed
def do_mask_numpy(data, mask):
    return (np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint32) ^ mask).tobytes()

@timed
def make_data(datasize):
    ''' Make some random bytes '''
    return bytes(randrange(256) for _ in range(datasize))

datasize = 100000
mask = 0x12345678
data = make_data(datasize)

d1 = do_mask_arr1(data, mask)
d2 = do_mask_arr2(data, mask)
print(d1 == d2)

d3 = do_mask_numpy(data, mask)
print(d1 == d3)
```

**typical output**

```
make_data: 0.751557 seconds
do_mask_arr1: 0.026865 seconds
do_mask_arr2: 0.025110 seconds
True
do_mask_numpy: 0.000438 seconds
True
```

Tested using Python 3.6.0 on an old single core 32 bit 2GHz machine running on Linux.

I just did a run with `datasize = 4000000` and `do_mask_numpy` took 0.0422 seconds.

Comment: Actually it is possible to achieve a better result still using Python, anyhow numpy remains the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative in case you don't want to use numpy. The advantage comes from making a single comparison, while extending the mask size to the needed (depending on the datasize).

```
@timed
def do_mask_int(data, mask):
    intdata = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little', signed=False)
    strmask = format(mask,'0x')
    strmask = strmask * ((intdata.bit_length() + 31) // 32)
    n = intdata ^ int(strmask, 16)
    return n.to_bytes(((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8), 'little') or b'\0'
```

results are as it follows:

```
make_data: 8.288754 seconds
do_mask_arr1: 0.258530 seconds
do_mask_arr2: 0.253095 seconds
True
do_mask_numpy: 0.010309 seconds
True
do_mask_int: 0.060408 seconds
True
```

Still credits to numpy for being faster, but maybe one doesn't want to include it in production environment.

:]
Best

Comment: Very clever! You may be able to make it faster by replacing those divisions with shifts: `a // 32` -> `a >> 5`, `a // 8` -> `a >> 3`

Comment: not much actually

`make_data: 8.696361 seconds
do_mask_arr1: 0.260604 seconds
do_mask_arr2: 0.207433 seconds
True
do_mask_numpy: 0.006003 seconds
True
do_mask_int: 0.050470 seconds
True`